# Clean AirPods/EarPods Earwax?

Tags: headphones, airpods

I read about people sucking on the mesh part to get the wax out but that isn’t very effective/sanitary...wondering if there are any better ways to clean AirPods/EarPods when earwax inevitably collects on them?

Comment: Wax also reduces the volume levels of the AirPods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE: Before using Putty, I recommend using a Q-Tip/tissue to clean the surface (while being careful not to push anything into the mesh).

---

Wall/Mounting Putty works wonders!

Any brand is fine (likely available in your local drugstore), here’s an [example](https://www.target.com/p/scotch-removable-mounting-putty-2-oz/-/A-13356391):

[image: Scotch Removable Mounting Putty]

Push your AirPods/EarPods (1 at a time) into the putty as much as you can, and then pull them out and you’ll see a bunch of dirt left over on the putty! So satisfying and they’re good as new.