# Lost one side of AirPods, buy another side to complete the pair

Tags: airpods

I lost my left AirPod. Can I buy a right AirPod (used) and pair it with my left one?

Comment: Not to be nit-picking - but wouldn't it be a lot wiser to buy a _left_ AirPod instead of ending up with two AirPods for the _right_ ear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: Yes it's quite possible a used AirPod (only risk is incompatibility) can be paired to your current AirPod by following these [directions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207827) (quoted below).

---

Apple's [If your AirPods are lost](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207581) article is a good starting point (originally linked by [IconDaemon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/22824/icondaemon)).

*Before seeking a replacement, make sure you've attempted to find the missing AirPod using Find My iPhone.*

If you need to replace it, Apple recommends you "get the serial number and then contact Apple Support for a replacement" - presumably to make sure their versions are compatible.

Regarding setup, you can check out [Set up your replacement AirPods or charging case](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207827):

> 1. Put both AirPods in your charging case.
> 2. Open the lid and check the status light. It should flash amber.
> 3. Press and hold the setup button on the back of the case for 5 seconds. The status light should flash white. If it still flashes
>      amber, connect the case to power, close the lid, and wait 10 minutes.
> 4. On your iPhone, go to the Home screen.
> 5. Open the case—with your AirPods inside—and hold it next to your iPhone. A setup animation appears on your iPhone.
> 6. Tap Connect, then tap Done.

If you're interested in buying a replacement directly from Apple, you can find more information under [AirPods Repair](https://support.apple.com/airpods/repair/service) (note that this is US specific, you can find the locale specific page [here](https://support.apple.com/airpods/repair/service/localeselector)), where they list a replacement of a lost AirPod as costing $69 + tax + $6.95 shipping fee.

---

I personally would not want to use somebody's used AirPod, but if necessary I would [clean out the earwax](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310432/clean-airpods-earpods-earwax) and wipe it down with a tissue soaked in hand sanitizer.

Answer (score 3):

I have had a long journey with an apple replacement airpod not wanting to pair with the other. I got the following response, after calling them, which to my surprise actually worked:

> 1. Make sure the AirPods are unpaired by going to Settings Bluetooth AirPods Tap the (i) Forget this Device on the companion iOS device
>      (this step is important).
> 2. Connect a lightning cable to the customer’s Charging Case and connect to a power source.
> 3. Place both AirPods in the case and put them within 4 inches of their iOS device (be sure they are not on/using the phone during this
>      part).
> 4. Close the lid and wait 35 minutes. It is very important to wait the full 35 minutes with the lid closed. If this process is interrupted at
>      all, it has to start over completely.
> 5. After the full uninterrupted 35 minutes, open the Charging Case lid.
> 6. Press and hold the “setup” button on the back of the AirPods charging case until the status light flashes white. This may take up
>      to a full minute.
> 7. The AirPods should now be ready to be setup through the standard setup process

I am wondering if this process also works if two diffrent AirPods with diffrent serial numbers which in this case would fix the many "can i buy a used one to replace my lose one ?".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to order a single AirPod from Apple and pair it alongside your existing one. The only requirement being that both airpods should be from the same generation.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this, or a link where such an order can be placed?

Comment: AirPod(s) Service [details](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207581) (scroll down.)

Comment: What if I buy a used one and pair?