# What are the best ways to clean your airpods and airpod case?

Tags: audio, headphones, airpods

My AirPod case & headphones get dirty often. I've used a damp paper towel to clean the exterior of the case, a combo of a cotton swab and even a tooth pick for some of the tighter areas on the inside of the case and the headphones, though it's never perfect.

What are the best practices to easily clean your AirPod case & headphones?

Comment: Does this help? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208729

Comment: I've always just followed the directions from Apple (as @SteveChambers indicated).

Comment: Related: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/1/6973

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/310432/151404

Answer (score 0):

I use a cotton bud for the earphones themselves by removing the caps
from the buds, then cleaning as I would my own ears.

Next I use a thin microfibre cloth to get between the lid and the case
(I have to half close the lid to get it in there).

After that I follow up with a cloth/bud for the rest of the case with a small amount of isopropyl alcohol which evaporates quickly.